# How to make a Rails app on Google App Engine redirect to HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, https, gcloud

I have successfully deployed my Rails app to the Google App Engine (my domain is also hosted by Google), and now I would like to redirect anyone going to my http:// address to my https:// address.

I have found the documentation to do so for a Python app [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) using the `handlers` element in the `app.yaml` file, and have attempted to replicate it in my own.

My `app.yaml` file now contains this:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
script: config/application.rb
secure: always
redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

However I can still visit http:// without being redirected, and I think that it's because of the `script: config/application.rb` option that I've passed. I have no idea which file I should use or what that file should contain in a Rails app. Deployment breaks if I do not pass the `script` option.

Let me know if you need any more info, and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In this case it's the fact that it's a Rails app that makes it unique. Other answers have answered the same question for Python/Java etc, but none for Rails yet.

Comment: @FelixFortis The doc you mentioned is for the standard environment, Ruby is only supported on the flexible one. This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'm new to gcloud and that was very helpful

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944776/force-ssl-on-app-engine-flexible-environment-custom-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can enforce SSL through your app's `config/environments/production.rb` file, you just need to add one line:

```
Rails.application.configure do
    # Other code...
    config.force_ssl = true # add this line to force HTTPS on production 
end
```

This will do 3 things for your application, actually:

1. TLS redirect
2. Secure cookies: Sets the `secure` flag on cookies
3. HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)

Read more about your application's configuration at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html